# Signs outside brackets in the chemfig environment

Tags: brackets, chemfig, chemistry

I'm using chemfig environment inside Latex and I have a big molecule inside brackets.
I need to put a plus sign outside the brackets.

`\chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---=--)} \chemright)` (The plus sign must be here)

Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: What have you tried to do? You will get a lot more help if you show how far you have come and where the exact problem lies. You should also write a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to get

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---=--)} \chemright{)^{+}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @CrocoDuck!